# fatal error: linux/i2c-dev.h: No such file or directory 34 | #include <linux/i2c-dev.h>

Tags: drivers

In my Ubuntu 20.4 virtual machine I have installed RIOT OS for IOT devices. I am experiencing this error when  compiling the program main.c (this take place by the command make BOARD=nucleo-f401re) that should have access to a I2C sensor readings. What is wrong ?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install linux-libc-dev` to  get this header for amd64 arch.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in terminal:

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

and try compiling again. On my system, i2c-dev.h is part of the kernel headers of the kernel that I use.

Comment: Unfortunately I tried to install the linux headers but  nothing changed after compiling.

Comment: Does `/usr/include/linux/i2c-dev.h` exist on your system? Run `ls /usr/include/linux/i2c-dev.h` or `file /usr/include/linux/i2c-dev.h`

Comment: Yes it exists!  I have also followed the instructions in this post https://www.tecmint.com/install-kernel-headers-in-ubuntu-and-debian/ . But nothing. the error still there.

Comment: Sounds like a compiler config issue. Try passing the path manually, add `-I/usr/include`  to your compiler command: `gcc -I/usr/include main.c -o out.bin` and see if that works. I hope that does work.

Comment: I tried to compile with the command "gcc -I/usr/include main.c -o out.bin" but now there is another error fatal error: xtimer.h: No such file or directory. But it is important to refer that i usually compile with a make within RIOT OS and there is a Makefile which is included in the make. So May be they are not equivalent way of compiling.

Comment: `xtimer.h` appears to be specific to that platform, see `https://doc.riot-os.org/xtimer_8h.html` so you will need to re-assess the steps you have taken and make sure you have installed everything you need at the right places. Go to `https://github.com/RIOT-OS/Tutorials` and scroll down to "Preparations" under "Tutorials for RIOT" - the steps you need to take are listed. Also see `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tS5W9COQOcI` and `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4qgyXcPydmM` - I hope some of that helps.

Comment: I have already followed all useful steps form the Riot Os Tutorial. Anyway I suppose that these resources such use usr/include/Linux/ should be declared in the Makefile in some way . Although I do not know how!